# Validation in cakephp for password is not working

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

i am using following code in model to validate password in cakephp 2.X

```
    'password' => array(
    'ruleName' => array(
        'rule' => '(^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$)',
        'message' => "Password should contain: 8 characters, 1 upper case, 1 lower case, 1 number."
    )
),
```

Can you please tell where I am wrong. on form submit I always get a same message;

> Password should contain: 8 characters, 1 upper case, 1 lower case, 1
>   number.

even if i add valid password like `"QWert123"`

Comment: I think you also need at least one of these characters here : `#?!@$%^&*-`. To be confirmed but have a look at this part.

Comment: i have even tried  QWert123!
the same is working fine in my older cakephp version

Comment: http://regexr.com/3adhh `QWert123!` match the expression here. If it works in another cakephp version, the issue does not come from the RegEx itself. (I do not know CakePHP so I can't help you more here, hope you will find something!)

Answer (score 2):

The regex pattern do not match on this part `(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])` for password `"QWert123"` because you don't have one of the characters in the password. In this case you can make it optional though

```
'rule' => '(^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]*).{8,}$)',
```

**EDIT:** In cakephp2.X, `custom` validation is used when using regular expression is needed [cakephp docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html)

```
'rule' => array('custom','(^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]*).{8,}$)'),
```

Comment: I have tried this. this is not working..
the same validation code is working in my older cakephp version..

Comment: @user123456 i have edited my answer. I've tried it already in my local